# Error when putting a condition on a join

Tags: sql, db2, inner-join

thank you in advance. Basically I have a working pull but when I add the line | and res.TYPE like ''%man%'' | which is a condition on the join of the second table I brought in, I get no results. I do however get results with the redacted line in the code found below. The reason I'm putting this condition is because there are multiple entries I'm getting for different TYPES within a single record, but I only want to see the ones that have man contained in it. Meaning I see the same CLMID multiple times with different TYPE like this. 123 has a record of MAN, GUY, and FEMALE but I only want to see the MAN record so I can see the YEAR only for the MAN

```
select distinct clm.POLDATE, clm.ACCDATE, clm.CLMID, clm.POLEID, res.YEAR, res.TYPE
from admin.table1 clm
join admin.table2 res
on clm.CLMID = res.CLMID
where clm.POLDATE>=''2018-01-01''
and (clm.POLEID like ''IFP%'' or clm.POLEID like ''OBG%'' or clm.POLEID like ''OFP%'')
order by clm.POLDATE asc
```

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: no error message, I just no results on my table. query runs successfully. and DB2 I believe. the issue is when run the above query I get many results but when I add in and res.TYPE like ''%man%'' and requery I get no results

Comment: Is that a working or non-working query you have shown us? Can you add the other one as well?

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys I answered my own question, I had to capitalize MAN to get it to work.